# Postnikov tower of a product

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be simply connected, locally finite CW-complexes and let $(X_i)_i$ and $(Y_i)_i$ be their Postnikov towers respectively.

Is the Postnikov tower of $X\times Y$ given by the products $(X_i \times Y_i)_i$ with the obvious maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

The condition on homotopy groups (vanishing in higher degree, isomorphism in lower degree) is satisfied for the products.

And the product of two fibrations is a fibration, so all involved maps are fibrations.